# ¿Por qué me dal el error "Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes"?

Tags: react-native, npm

Tengo un  problema un tanto extraño al momento de crear un proyecto en React native. Cuando utilizo el comando:

```
npx react-native init nombreapp
```

Me da el error:

```
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "Gironás": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Daniel Gironás Perez\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-05T04_55_23_493Z-debug.log
Install for [ 'react-native@latest' ] failed with code 1
```

¿El error está en el nombre de la carpeta Usuario?

Answer (score 2):

El problema radica en el nombre, tal y como te dice el error:

> Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
>
> <sub>(Las Tags no pueden tener caracteres que encodeURIComponent codifique)</sub>

Mirando la documentación de [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) vemos que allí nos da pista de qué caracteres son estos:

> encodeURIComponent() escapes all characters except:
>
> Not Escaped:
>
> A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )

Es decir: `encodeURIComponent()` escapa todos los caracteres excepto las letras, los números y los caracteres - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ).

Como en el nombre "Gironás" aparece una tilde, esta no forma parte de los caracteres permitidos y de ahí el error. Sustituye la "á" por una "a" y todo funcionará.

Comment: Es justo lo que pensaba, el problema es que esa carpeta no se le puede cambiar de forma simple debido a que es una carpeta que se genera al momento de instalar el sistema.

Comment: Solo por si acaso, el problema lo solucione creando un nuevo usuario administrador en windows

Comment: ah qué bueno @Daniel